# Expectation of a continuous random variable with probability one at a given point.

Tags: probability, integration, expectation

$$f_{X}(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{x+1}{a+1} & -1 \leq x < a \\
1 & x=a \\
\frac{x-1}{a-1} & a < x \leq 1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Calculate $E(X)$

I know typically this is a very easy solution (sum the three integrals, integrating between the limits given in the PDF) but in this case, the $P_X$(x)=1 when x=a is throwing me a little.  Is that integral =1, a,  $a^2$/2 or 0?  I suppose the question then is really what should my limits on that integration be?  Or even, can I even integrate that, bearing in mind its a point function?

Thanks!

P.S, I apologis for my formatting; please feel free to edit.

Comment: The probability at a point in continous distribution is $0$.

Comment: This is a continuous random variable , so just because the PDF evaluated at $f_{X}(a)= 1$ does **not** mean the probability that $x=a$ is 1

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you.  So does that mean then that the E[X] is only the sum of the integrals for the first and third lines in the pdf?

Comment: I would advise drawing the pdf. $f$ is not a point function at $a$ (that is, there isn't an atom there, which I think is what you believe).

Answer (score 1):

The probabiity density function at $x=a$ takes the value $1$ does not imply that the probability at $x=a$ is $1$. 
Because the probability at $x=a$ is given by $P(x=a)=P(a\le x \le a)=\int^{a}_{a}f(x) dx = 0$ 
So $$E(X)=\int^{1}_{-1} xf(x) dx=\int^{a}_{-1}\frac{x^2+x}{a+1} dx +\int^{a}_{a}x dx+\int^{1}_{a} \frac{x^2-x}{a-1} dx$$

Now you see what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the value of a function **at a single point** is irrelevant to an integral of that function.  I will add, however, that before you can determine the expectation, you will have to determine the correct value of "a"- that value such that the "total probability", the integral of that probability density function from -1 to 1, is 1.

I spoke to soon- that integral **is** 1 for all a!